# how to use value of a variable when declaring a tcl list

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to use variable in tcl list declaration?
I have the following simple example:

```
set grape_color "green"

set produce_list {\
   { PRODUCE COLOR             REGION  }\
   { APPLE   "red"             TX }\
   { GRAPE   $grape_color      CA }\
}

puts $produce_list
```

The output of the code is this:

```
{ PRODUCE COLOR             REGION  } 
{ APPLE   "red"             TX }
{ GRAPE   $grape_color      CA }
```

but I want "green" instead of `$grape_color` in the list.

Answer (score 5):

One way you can do it is by using the `list` command.

```
set grape_color green
set produce_list [list \
    [list PRODUCE COLOR        REGION] \
    [list APPLE   red          TX] \
    [list GRAPE   $grape_color CA]]
```

Another way is by using the `subst` command.

```
set grape_color green
set produce_list {
    { PRODUCE COLOR        REGION }
    { APPLE   red          TX }
    { GRAPE   $grape_color CA }
}
set produce_list [subst -nobackslashes -nocommands $produce_list]
```

Comment: I recommend using the first option (despite it being ugly); the second will run into problems with multi-word substitutions (e.g., “`Lemon Yellow`”).

Comment: I think it would be prudent to explain this behaviour, i.e braces prevent variable substitution